# MIT License Question (download somebody else's code and throw it on github)

Tags: licensing, version-control, github, mit-license

Sometimes I use plugins and 3rd party libraries, and one thing that drives me crazy is when these libraries are not versioned. So, if I download it, make some mods to it, I am the only person in the world who can benefit from it... well, until I version it myself.

My question is simple: if a library I find online has an MIT License, would it violate the license if I download it, modify it, and put it on github?

I'm not trying to pass it off as my own, I'm just trying to help the community benefit from my work. A lot of libraries are pretty nice, but for some reason they aren't versioned...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding (I am not a lawyer) for the MIT license that would be fine as long as you maintain the license and the original copyright notice.

Comment: this is the way i understood it as well, although i'm not nerdy enough to read the license :P i did notify the author that i would like to add it to github and he said he would add it himself. i figured it's just common courtesy to notify the author before doing that.

Comment: It's one of the shortest licenses going, have a read! http://opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php/ Good point on notifying the author, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @James Even if a legal agreement is *short*, and you can understand the *intent*, you may still need to consult a lawyer to understand what *effect* the agreement has in any particular jurisdiction. It may even be completely unenforceable and have no meaning whatsoever.

Comment: Sure, hence the "I am not a lawyer", but seriously - it's one of the shortest and clearest open source licenses going. If you can't even be bothered to read it how are you going to talk to your lawyer about it?

Answer (score 0):

MIT license is pretty permissive, most things you want to do with the code should be acceptable (IANAL, though).  It would definitely be considered good form to maintain attribution to the original author of the code though, ("Originally written by Freddy Foobar, modifications by Betty Bazquux", for example)